# Jasmine-compatible TypeScript object equality library

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, object-equality

Disclaimer: TypeScript (and more generally JavaScript) object equality functions have been discussed en-masse here (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496057) and everywhere else (e.g., https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-object-comparison).
I am **not** looking for any code snippets (there are more than enough in [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183)). There are various libraries ([underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore), [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash), [fast-deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal), [fast-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-equals), [nano-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano-equal), etc.) for object equality checking, but it's hard to understand the differences between them.

What I miss in most questions and answers about TypeScript object equality is **unit testing**.
Because the testing framework decides what should be considered "equal".
I use *Jasmine* for unit tests, thus the [`toEqual(…)`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toEqual) method governs object equality.

For example, `JSON.stringify(…)` is not consistent with Jasmine's `toEqual(…)` because `JSON.stringify(…)` is sensitive to property order:

```js
JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) != JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1});

expect({a:1, b:2}).toEqual({b:2, a:1});
```

For *full consistency*, an equality check would have to yield the same result as Jasmine's `toEqual(…)` for every conceivable input.

I am aware that Jasmine supports [custom equality testers](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_equality), but these should only be used for special cases.

Question: Are any of the aforementioned equality libraries **fully consistent** with [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/index.html)'s `toEqual(…)`?
If none of them are, which are the edge cases that yield different results than Jasmine?

*[Edit: Rephrased the question to avoid asking for subjective advice on off-site libraries; added two more equality libraries to the list; clarified what I mean by full consistency with Jasmine.]*

Comment: Asking for off-site libraries is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks for the reminder. Would the question remain on-topic if rephrased to "Are any of the aforementioned libraries fully consistent with Jasmine's 'toEqual(…)' method?"

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be off-topic, but would probably garner downvotes, since you can test them as easily (if not more easily) than anyone else can.

Comment: Have you looked at Jasmine's `toEqual` implementation? Can you share its source code?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I have rephrased the question as discussed. 
Could you please explain your concern about possible downvotes? 
I am neither a TypeScript expert nor affiliated with any of those projects. 
I asked the question because I assume there are slight functional differences between equality libraries (e.g., whether functions are ignored, cycle detection, '=='-vs-'===' strictness of equality for primitive fields, or other subtle considerations as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471).

Comment: @Bergi, The corresponding Jasmine source code https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/e022e6199c77482b1e2c9b683590f791909b6216/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L168 states that it was "lovingly adopted from Underscore". This is a good hint but I since the code was "adopted" I am not sure whether it's functionally equivalent.

Comment: @MyKey_ Ah I guess the major distinction from Underscore is that Jasmine builds a diff to be printed, for showing *what* the difference is instead of just returning a boolean. So yeah, it's hard to tell what exactly it does.